# How to add blank UITableViewCell in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to load 2 uiTableViewCells with the second being blank.  The result I'm after is to make each alternating cells appear to float. All of the questions/answers I see add information in both cells.  Here is a screenshot of my Storyboard on what I'm trying to do...

[image]

Can I present these 2 cells on top of each other? How?

Answer (score 0):

Do you require sections in your tableview? If not, you could change the tableview style to "Grouped" and this will implement spacing between each section.

[image]

If you use a section per cell, you will get a default spacing size between each cell.

Comment: How would I get individual array elements into each individual section?  Right now I'm returning 1 for numberOfRowsInSection, array.count for sectionsInTableView, and accessing them with array[indexPath.row].

Comment: Number of sections == array.count, number of rows == 1

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are looking for is extra spacing between the cells, you can do that with one tableview cell and it will be much cleaner.

- make the height of the cell the combined height of the content + spacing
- make the background of the cell either transparent or the color that you want the spacing to be between the cells
- add a uiview that would sit at the top (or some distance from the top if you want some padding there as well). This will be the view you use for your content.
- adjust the height of the newly added subview to show the correct amount of padding you are after, and add the proper constraints.
- add your image view, label, and anything else you want to display in your cell as a subview of the uiview you added in the third step, and make their constraints relative to that view.